# Is it possible to change the default filenames for disks in an OVA/OVF?

Tags: virtualbox

I generated an OVA with multiple virtual machines in it. The OVA was named Cluster.ova.

Now if I try to import it, the default disk names in the import dialog are `Cluster-disk1`, `Cluster-disk2`, `Cluster-disk3`, etc.

What I actually want though is `Machine1-disk1`, `Machine1-disk2`, `Machine2-disk1`, etc. (This is what I had before I exported the OVA).

Is there a way to set the default disk filenames in my OVA? Preferably without re-exporting it?

Answer (score 0):

IIRC,  once they are shutdown (NOT PAUSED) you can run a vbox manage --rename foo bar  then relaunch them

Comment: You can't shutdown an OVA file. Please read my question again.